# boost locking mutex deadlocks

Tags: multithreading, boost

I have code that I am trying to guard using boost locking mechanism. **The problem is that RecomputeStuff can not only be called from RemoveStuff, but it can also be called from another thread.** My question is, using these boost locking mechanisms, what is the correct way to fix RecomputeStuff? The way it is now it deadlocks.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::shared_mutex values_mutex;

int globaldata;

class A
{
public:
    void RecomputeStuff();
    void RemoveStuff();
private:
    std::vector<std::string> data;
};

//Note, RecomputeStuff just reads from std::vector<std::string> data, but it also writes to other global stuff that RemoveStuff also writes to.
void A::RecomputeStuff()
{
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(values_mutex);
    boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>  unique_lock(lock);

    // this function reads std::vector<std::string> data
    // but also modifies `globaldata` that RemoveStuff also modifies.
}

void A::RemoveStuff()
{
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(values_mutex);
    boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>  unique_lock(lock);

    //here, remove stuff from std::vector<std::string> data
    //...then call RecomputeStuff

    RecomputeStuff();

    // modify `globaldata`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to move the not locked code of the `A::RecomputeStuff` method to a separate one and call it from the `A::RemoveStuff` and `A::RecomputeStuff`. See the code below

```
boost::shared_mutex values_mutex;

int globaldata;

class A
{
private:
    void RecomputeStuffUnsafe();
public:
    void RecomputeStuff();
    void RemoveStuff();
private:
    std::vector<std::string> data;
};

void A::RecomputeStuffUnsafe()
{
    // this function reads std::vector<std::string> data
    // but also modifies `globaldata` that RemoveStuff also modifies.
}


//Note, RecomputeStuff just reads from std::vector<std::string> data, but it also writes to other global stuff that RemoveStuff also writes to.
void A::RecomputeStuff()
{
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(values_mutex);
    boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>  unique_lock(lock);

    RecomputeStuffUnsafe();
}

void A::RemoveStuff()
{
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(values_mutex);
    boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>  unique_lock(lock);

    //here, remove stuff from std::vector<std::string> data
    //...then call RecomputeStuff

    RecomputeStuffUnsafe();

    // modify `globaldata`
}
```

**Edit #00:**

Also `upgrade_lock` has a [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.upgrade_lock) which accepts the [try_to_lock_t](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_option) tag. It looks like what you are asking for.